# change process name linux

Tags: linux, process, ps

I have the following problem. I run a program in parallel using mpirun. This program called SIESTA, needs arguments. Here is how I run it:

mpirun -np 3 siesta < input.fdf > log &

The "mpirun -np 3" set the number of processors/cores used.
The "siesta < input.fdf > log" specify the executable program name ("siesta"), the input file ("input.fdf") and the output file ("log").

My problem is that when running different input files, I always have the same process name resulting from the PS command, in this case, the SIESTA process name for all the running process with different inputs.

I would like to know how to setup an script in order to set the process name different, for example, equal to the input file name. Then, when I run:

mpirun -np 3 siesta < inputAAA.fdf > log &
mpirun -np 3 siesta < inputBBB.fdf > log &

I will like to have two process running with names:
inputAAA
inputBBB

so I can kill the wright process in case of problems.

Regards,

Hatuey